# Fixing outgoing message in suds SOAP request

Tags: python, soap, suds

My suds request produces invalid message once calling soap WS.
There are two things to do that i've spend hours on with no success:

- Add a namespace and prefix to one of complex obejcts (`securityObject`)
- Add an attribute to another complex object (`Document`)

My client:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.6

Service ( MyService ) tns="http://path/to/tns"
  Prefixes (4)
      ns0 = "http://path/to/v3/"
      ns1 = "http://path/to/tns"
      ns2 = "http://www.path/to/file.001.xsd"
      ns3 = "http://www.path/to/file.002.xsd"
   Ports (1):
      (MyServiceSOAP)
         Methods (1):
            processAction(ns2:Document Document, ns0:securityObject securityObject PriorityType priority)
         Types (233):
            ns0:securityObject
            PriorityType
            ns3:Document
            ns2:Document
            ns3:AccountIdentification4Choice
            …
```

**1st** method argument:

Because `ns2:Document Document` is quite big and complex and I already **have** valid XML i will pass this as a `processAction` parameter in following form:

```
from suds.sax.text import Raw
_doc.open('file.xml').read()
doc = Raw(_doc) # ready to pass
```

This is how this doc looks like:
`<Document xmlns="http://www.path/to/file.001.xsd">...</Document>`

**2nd** method argument:

Is security object:

```
s_o = client.factory.create('{http://path/to/v3/}securityObject')
s_o.name = token_data.Name
s_o.user = token_data.Tenant
s_o.timestamp = token_data.Time.isoformat()
s_o.pass = token_data.Passwd
```

Let's send:

```
try:
    process_data = client.service.processAction(s_o, doc, prio.NORMAL)
except suds.WebFault as e:
    print e
```

Outgoing (invalid) message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    # in client its "http://path/to/v3/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://path/to/tns"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                   # missing xmlns:v3="http://path/to/v3/" here!
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns1:payment>
            <securityObject>    # wrong! shall be <v3:securityObject> 
                <user>1</user>
                <name>MyName</name>
                <timestamp>2016-06-22T11:40:58.115000+02:00</timestamp>
                <pass>Password</pass>
            </securityObject>
            <Document>                                             # wrong, missing attribute here, xmlns= 
                <Document xmlns="http://www.path/to/file.001.xsd"> # comes from orginal xml, can be trimmed
```

Message that will success requires two fixes:

1. adding a namspace and prefix for  to look like below:

   ```
   xmlns:v3="http://path/to/v3/"  # this to be added in Envelope
   <v3:securityObject>
       ...
   </v3:securityObject>
   ```
2. Adding an attribute to `ns2:Document` object, so it will look like:
   `<Document xmlns="http://www.path/to/file.001.xsd">`
   (This will require stripping  tag from orginal message that i create. I can do that but it seems not quite elegant.)
   *Ideally* would it be to map the content of my XML into `ns2:Document` object with one single method.

Here is how suds handles those objects:

```
(Content){
   tag = "Document"
   value = "<Document xmlns="http://www.path/to/file.001.xsd">
                <CfInitn>
                    <GrpHdr>
                    ...

(Content){
   tag = "securityObject"
   value = 
      (securityObject){
         user= 1
         name = "MyName"
         timestamp = "2016-06-22T12:51:29.820000+02:00"
         pass= "Password"
      }
```

Any help much apreciated, thanks!

Comment: there https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#CUSTOMSOAPHEADERS